# With pure JavaScript, is there an easy way to attach an event listener to a class?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for the JavaScript equivalent of

```
$(".class-name").on(eventName, eventHandler);
```

first I tried

```
document.querySelectorAll(".class-name").addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler);
```

but it didn't work. Is there an easy way to do it in JavaScript?

------Update------

Many answers suggested a loop, but originally I was looking for a solution with a single listener to save memory (suppose I had 1000 items in that class). 
However, one answer reminded me: does the jQuery version also create 1000 listeners in the memory?

Comment: use `.addEventListener`

Comment: Well note that jQuery *is* JavaScript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Look into console and you'll see that there is no `on` in pureJS.

Comment: @panther there's no `querySelectorAll()` or `addEventListener()` in **JavaScript** either. Those are browser APIs and not part of the programming language.

Comment: To be more constructive: you'll want to create an event handler function and affix it to the `document` object. Have it check the event target by examining the event object, and then use `.matches()` to compare the event target to your selector like `.on()` does in jQuery.

Comment: Wow, 6 answers - That usually suggests this would have been an easy one to Google.

Comment: Sorry guys, there was a typo when I first submitted the question. I edited within 30 seconds, but comments and answers already came in.

Comment: @DrZYin My answer uses a single listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery will assign the event handler passed to `on` to all the elements that match the selector. Vanilla JS does not do this. `document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` and so you'll need to select the specific node you want and assign the event listeners to it. If you want to assign the event listener to all the nodes in the list, then you may iterate over the `NodeList` like so:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".class-name");
for (var node in nodes) {
    node.addEventListener(event, handler);
}
```

Comment: No, I didn't! Good catch!

Comment: Does jQuery create multiple listeners in the memory?

Comment: If you're asking if jQuery assigns the same instance of the passed in handler to the event, then yes. You can see that happening here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L106

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over `document.getElementsByClassName('this-is-the-class-you-are-searching-for')` like

```
document.getElementsByClassName('selector-class').forEach(function (e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    console.log('Oh dang, you just clicked!');
  });
});
```

As Alex M. pointed out, the NodeList.forEach is not supported by some browsers such as InternetExplorer. So, you could use a different syntax (`for`) or use a transpiler like babel to ensure the wide support of your code! The [polyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill) is also very small.

Comment: Just be aware that `NodeList.prototype.forEach` is necessarily widely supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Answer (score 0):

Here's the equivalent (this will also work for future nodes)

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var el = e.target;
  if (el.classList.contains("class-name")) {
    // handle event e for element el
  }
});
```

Edit: while the same is possible in jQuery, this way is actually superior to the example from the Question. This listener will also catch clicks on elements that didn't exist when the listener was added.

Answer (score 0):

Store all elements in array and bind event to all of them. Here `document.getElementsByClassName` returns array of element having class `class-name`.

```js
var classes= document.getElementsByClassName("class-name");

 Array.from(classes).forEach(function(element) {
      element.addEventListener('click', function(){alert('clicked'+   this.innerHTML)});
    });
```

```html
<div class="class-name">
First div  1
</div>

<div class="class-name">
Second div    2
</div>

<div class="class-name">
third div   3
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="class-name">
nth div     n
</div>
```

**Edit**

`getElementsByClassName` doesnt return an array, but a HTMLCollection in most, or a NodeList is some browsers ([Mozila ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)). Both of these types are Array-Like, (meaning that they have a length property and the objects can be accessed via their index), but are not strictly an Array or inherited from an Array. (meaning other methods that can be performed on an Array cannot be performed on these types)

Answer (score 0):

The issues is `querySelectorAll` returns a nodeList, if you only looked for one class using `querySelector`, your code would work, but only bind to one element.

#### Option 1: Iterate over NodeList + Bind

One option is to iterate over all the nodes in the nodelist and bind the event to them:

```js
let eventName = 'click';
let elements  = document.querySelectorAll('.foo');
[...elements].forEach(el=>el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler));


function eventHandler (){
  console.log(`Clicked: "${this.textContent}"`);
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">Click Me</div>
<div class="foo">Or this</div>
```

Note: the above uses ES6 syntax, if you need an iteration method that is a little more compliant, you can try:
`[].forEach.call(elements, function(el) { ... });`

#### Option 2: Bind Once to Common Ancestor

Another option would be to find the closest common ancestor and bind one event to that, then see if the class you care about is the target and call the function, if so.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, absolutely!

EDIT: Turns out you want to add it to every element with that class. In that case you should try with

`let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")`

After that you could just cycle through them with a for loop and attach the event listener.

Comment: But that is not the question

Comment: Read the question once again.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Check the edit, it should be what he's looking for